# Why do I keep getting a failed when trying to make a .cer for testing?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to make a certificate for testing and I am using this site *[How to: Create Your Own Test Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx)* as a tutorial on how to but when it comes time to enter in the password after you create the password it says failed in the command prompt why is that?

What I've done:

First, I open a command prompt and type in:

```
  cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
```

Second, I type in

```
  makecert -sv myPrivateKeyFile.pvk -n "TestCert" myCertFile.cer -b 01/01/2011 -e 01/01/2015 -r
```

Then I create the password then enter the password on the sencond pop up box and then it says failed in command prompt

When I enter in this again, the popup is asking for the password pops up first this time, and I enter it in and it says:

> Error: CryptCertStrToNameW failed => 0x80092023 (-2146885597)

```
    makecert -sv myPrivateKeyFile.pvk -n "TestCert" myCertFile.cer -b 01/01/2011 -e 01/01/2015 -r
```

Comment: ... because you didn't do something right? Show what you've done, otherwise your question is unanswerable.

Comment: updated my post to show what i have done

Comment: Two ideas: If you have more than one makecert.exe on your system, make sure you're running the latest one. If that's not it, did you actually type the "TestCert" part or did you paste it from, say, a Word document? If so, the quotes themselves may be from an unsupported character set.

Comment: And a third: Try changing your computer's date/time to something other than leap day :)

Comment: sorry i have not posted back when you posted your comment my power went out and i didnt think about my post till now when im back to programing, i did type it out and its the only makecert.exe i can find how can i make sure its uptodate?

Comment: Because the name you are using is not valid.
Use the syntax -n "CN=TestCert"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why I was getting this error is, because I didn't right click on cmd when I ran it. So when you have this problem you need to right click on cmd and then run as administrator and see if that fixes your problem as it did mine.

Answer (score 74):

I solved the problem by running the program as an administrator, but I had to change also the name of certificate in a LDAP style like this (CN=...):

```
makecert -sv myPrivateKeyFile.pvk -n "CN=TestCert" myCertFile.cer -b 01/01/2011 -e 01/01/2015 -r
```

Comment: Interesting. The "CN=" thing helped me here. What's the influence of that prefix? Can someone explain?

Comment: "CN=" is part of the X.500 standard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.500 "CN" stands for "common name".  See the naming conventions on the LDAP protocol.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol

Answer (score 5):

This was a bit of a shotgun-debug for me. I started with this after reading the [makecert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/ff548309) guide:

> `makecert.exe  /b 01/01/2014 /e 01/01/2114 /len 256 /m 1200 /n "CN=In-House-Software" /pe /r /sr localMachine Test_Cert.cer`

There's two error-causing flaws here:

1. `/e` and `/m` likely are not supposed to overlap; seems kind of obvious, but they didn't document it or create an expressive error message for it.
2. `/len 256` was an invalid value -- too low. This also didn't seem too obvious/documented/expressed in a good error message. `512` did work. I didn't bother finding the floor-value, but by default `1024` is used.

I ended up using this with success:

> `makecert.exe /b 01/01/2014 /e 01/01/2114 /len 512 /pe /r /n "CN=In-House-Software" /sr localMachine Test_Cert.cer`

Answer (score 3):

I also received this error when I specified the CA name for a self-signed cert, in other words, if you specify the '-cy authority' and the '-r' options, then DON'T specify the CA name explicitly in the name via the -n option.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was by the publisher name not starting with "CN=".
This fixed the issue, I didn't need to run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I couldn't run makecert properly from Dropbox folders. So try moving it to a solid disk like C:\ and try again.